# set icon for iPad with app's target device is iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode5

I set my app's target device to **iPhone**

[image]

then, I can only set icon for **iPhone** and cannot set icon for **iPad**:

[image]

So when I download the app from **iPad with iOS7**, the icon on iPad is default white one.

Comment: This is expected behaviour. What were you expecting?

Comment: @ShaggyFrog  there is no icon on iPad with iOS7

Comment: You dont need to set icon for iPad, whenever you execute you iphone application in iPad device it automatically get 2x icon, so 2x icon is automatically use for ipad.

Comment: @DipenChudasama it works on iPad with iOS 6 and below but not works on iPad with iOS7.

Comment: you have to use prepo tools for genrating require icons images, it will genrate automaticall require icons for iphone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

just  navi to the attributes inspector ,and  select the  check box.[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `prepo` tool which is use for generating icons for ios device whether it is for `iPhone/iPad/Universal` accoding to your selection it will generate require size iCons Automatically. Download `PREPO` tools from MAC app store and just drag you icon in it and see the magic, Use genrated icons in you application it will work. please see below image for reference.
 [image]

Answer (score 1):

Find the answer:

- Step 1: Select images.xcassets, choose **New App Icon**:(it will named AppIcon-1 by default), in AppIcon-1, you can set all icons including iPad icons

[image]

- Step 2: Select TARGET of general tab,set source of App Icons to AppIcon-1:

[image]

Comment: Great thank you! Apple should be more intelligent in there developer interfaces though...

Answer (score 0):

You set `Devices` to iPhone, thus you will not get iPad icons, change your `Devices` to universal and the iPad icons will appear.

Edit:

try the ipad check boxes in the inspector:

[image]

Comment: universal means app can adapt both iPhone and iPad, but I designed my app according iPhone's size, can be downloaded on iPad.

Comment: so it is an iPhone app, and you don't need to add iPad icons.

Comment: @Veelian Just correct me if i am mistaken, if you download iPhone app on iPad it works fine right? or am i missing something here?

Comment: It is an iPhone app, user can download it on iPad and it works fine on iPad, the problem is : the app display icon correct on `iPad with iOS6 and below`, but no icon on `iPad with iOS7`

Comment: hmm ok, I got you, +1 for your good question, I will edit my answer.

Comment: Even if I only target iPhone, I still have the options to select iPad icons

Answer (score 0):

for iOS7 you should use icon of size 120 * 120 pix.

you can add an icon of 120*120 pix in setting where iPhone spotlight iOS 7 40 pt is mentioned